# multiple multi-configuration projects with shared axis on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, multi-configuration

we have a bunch of multi-configuration projects and all of them share one axis. is it possible to control it globally for all of them? at the moment it is a bit tedious to edit all projects and make sure that the axis is the same.
I can think of a hack with a control axis that then drives what command is being executed but I would rather keep the job separated with some global way to feed the values into their shared axis. Also, some of the jobs have more axis than others so this might not even be possible to hack it like that. Do I expect too much from jenkins here? :-)